# Linqtosql - Returning custom class with interface

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, repository, interface

Why can't I return as a new custom class (cms.bo.Site) which implements ISite?

```
public IQueryable<ISite> GetSites()
{
    return (from site in Db.Sites select new cms.bo.Site(site.id, site.name));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically LINQ to SQL doesn't know what that constructor will do - it wants to try to convert that into a SQL query, but doesn't know how. Do you need to be able to add extra bits to the query afterwards? If not, you could do:

```
public IEnumerable<ISite> GetSites()
{
    return Db.Sites.Select(x => new { x.id, x.name }) // Project in SQL
                   .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest in process
                   .Select(x => new cms.bo.Site(x.id, x.name))
                   .Cast<ISite>(); // Workaround for lack of covariance
}
```

EDIT: I had missed the variance aspect, and was assuming the query was failing at execution time. It's definitely worth trying just the call to `Cast<ISite>()` as per tvanfosson's answer - but if that doesn't work, try the above :)

Comment: @Jon, I this wouldn't work because of generic type covariance: 
`IEnumerable<Site>` to `IEnumerable<ISite>`

Comment: Won't that return an IQyueryable<Site>, not an IQueryable<ISite>?

Comment: thanks guys and got it working with IQueryable. my head feels light again

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    return Db.Sites
             .ToList()
             .Select( s => new cms.bo.Site( s.id, s.name ) )
             .Cast<ISite>()
             .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I don't think you need the call to AsQueryable do you?

Comment: Don't have access to VS right now so I can't verify, but I think it might want to return it as IEnumerable<ISite> instead of IQueryable<ISite> otherwise.  That's probably ok, though since the query needs to be materialized in order to create the Site class, but it would change the return type of the method.